# Changing color of single UITableView Cell in iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I want to be able to change the color of a single UITableView cell. In my tableView(editActionsForRowAtIndexPath) I can swipe the cell and select a button to change the background color but when I scroll the cell off screen it changes back. How do I get it to retain the color? Thanks

Comment: If you want any changes to persist on scroll, you need to configure your cell on `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. Cells are reused.

Comment: You will need to store the indexpath of the UITableViewCell which has its color changes in an array, and in the method `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, check if the current indexpath is contained in the array. If yes, set the background colour, otherwise, leave it as it is.

Comment: This may sound stupid but what type of array would I make it? I can get the index path and know how to create the array but I can't figure out how to check the array. If that makes sense. Thanks

Comment: Please consider to mark an answer as correct, and if none of the answers are what you are looking for, edit your question to be more precise about the problem to improve chances of getting the correct answer

Comment: The answer from rach is correct but there is no way to mark it as such that I can see.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have only one section in your tableView with many rows, you need to do this in your tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: method:

```
if (indexPath.row == coloredCellIndex) {
     cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.RedColor()
} else {
     cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.WhiteColor()
}
```

You need to set the variable coloredCellIndex anywhere outside of this function, for example in viewDidLoad

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I can only write my answer in Objective-C. But I hope you can get my point.

If you are using a custom prototype cell, then you can add a property to your custom table view cell class, and store the current color you want for that cell, and then later in reload that color.

Sample code:

In CustomTableViewCell.h

```
@interface CustomTableViewCell : UITableViewCell

@property (nonatomic) UIColor *cellColor;

- (void)reloadBackgroundColor

@end
```

In CustomTableViewCell.m

```
- (void)reloadBackgroundColor
{
    self.backgroundColor = cellColor; //this is just a sample.
}
```

And then under you can just set that color everytime the cell is reloaded.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

CustomTableViewCell *tableCell = (CustomTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CustomTableCellIdentifier"];

[tableCell reloadBackgroundColor];

return tableCell;
```

Now, everytime you scroll the table, the color you want to set to that cell will be loaded.

If you are not using a custom prototype cell, then I suggest that you store the color you want for each cell in a Dictionary, with its index as the key. Then you just assign it again to that cell every time it is reloaded.

I hope this helps you. :)

Answer (score -1):

**Swift 3**

**viewDidLoad**

```
self.tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "CustomTableViewCell")
```

**cellForRowAt**

```
cell.backgroundColor = .black
```

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

let cell:CustomTableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "myCell") as! CustomTableViewCell

cell.accessoryType = .none
cell.backgroundColor = .black

return cell
}
```